# CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE issue

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm newbie in open CL, therefore would be appreciate if somebody can help.
I have a small kernel that always finished with CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE error. I've tried on different hardware gtx 765m or gtx 980, the result is the same.
Here is the code host + kernel:

```
//get all platforms (drivers)
std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
if(all_platforms.size()==0){
    std::cout<<" No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
    exit(1);
}
cl::Platform default_platform=all_platforms[1];
std::cout << "Using platform: "<<default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>()<<"\n";

//get default device of the default platform
std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
if(all_devices.size()==0){
    std::cout<<" No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
    exit(1);
}
cl::Device default_device=all_devices[0];
std::cout<< "Using device: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<"\n";

cl::Context context({default_device});

cl::Program::Sources sources;

std::string kernel_code=
        "__kernel void test(__global float* A,__global float* R) {"
            "int i = get_global_id(0);"
            "if(i<3000) {"
                "R[i]=0;"
                "return;"
            "} "
            "float vm=0;"
            "for(int j=i-3000;j<=i;++j)"
                "vm+=A[j];"
            "R[i]=vm;"
        "}";

sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()});

cl::Program program(context,sources);
if(program.build({default_device})!=CL_SUCCESS){
    std::cout<<" Error building: "<<program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)<<"\n";
    exit(1);
}

size_t n=1075021;
// create buffers on the device
cl::Buffer buffer_A(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(float)*n);
cl::Buffer buffer_R(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(float)*n);

float *A = new float[n];
float *R = new float[n];

srand (time(NULL));

for(size_t i=0;i<n;++i)
    A[i]=rand()%10;

//create queue to which we will push commands for the device.
cl::CommandQueue queue(context,default_device);

//write arrays A to the device
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(float)*n,A);
queue.finish();

//run the kernel
cl_int ret;
cl::Kernel kernel_test=cl::Kernel(program,"test");
kernel_test.setArg(0,buffer_A);
kernel_test.setArg(1,buffer_R);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_test,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(n),cl::NullRange);
ret=queue.finish();

//read result R from the device to array R
ret=queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_R,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(float)*n,R);
```

Comment: Check for error values of every single opencl call. The error is most likely happening before the actual kernel call.

Comment: I've checked the error value after every call, but the ret value is always 0, except the queue.finish after the kernel execution. Furthermore, if I change in the kernel code string vm+=A[j] to vm+=A[i], then it works fine, but I can't understand what the reason

Comment: there is the check "if(i<3000) {"  "R[i]=0;"
                "return;"
            "} " in the code before for cycle

Comment: I tried to run the code and it succeeds with both `vm+=A[j]` and `vm+=A[i]` on a i5-4460

Comment: It works fine on Intel and AMD hardware, but failed on NVIDIA, at least I've tested on gtx 670m, gtx 765m, gtx 980, but works absolutely fine on amd rx 580, intel open cl, or oclgrind simulator, unfortunately I have to to get it running on NVIDIA

Comment: The size of the workgroup is left for implementation to decide and your `n` is a prime number which I suspect means number of scheduled work groups will equal to `n` (local size being set to 1). Besides that's inefficient you may be hitting some hardware limit on nvidia. Try to round global size to say multiple of 64 and check (you will have to add a check to your kernel to not access data over your size `n`). Also use `.f` suffix for single floating point, some implementations are sensitive to it (kernel build will fail).

Comment: Thanks a lot, doqtor, it solved the issue!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, the rounding of the global work size just move the issue, now the error is occured if 3000 replaced by 65000, what is still works fine on amd and intel, but not on nvidia. Any ideas?

Comment: On nvidia you can round to multiple of 1024. Also specify explicitly 1024 as local size just in case implementation decide to choose different lower size.

Comment: @doqtor I use following code for rounding and kernel call now: 'size_t num_work_groups = (N-1) / _max_work_size + 1;
    size_t global_size_padded = num_work_groups * _max_work_size;
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(*kernel,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(global_size_padded),cl::NDRange(_max_work_size));' where _max_work_size is 1024, unfortunately it failed with the same error code if I use in the kernel 65000 instead of 3000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing what we've got in comments so far:

The number of global work items was set to 1075021 which is a prime number. Initially it was let the implementation to decide how the work is to be divided, which very likely was divided into 1075021 work groups with 1 work item each which besides being very inefficient was very likely hitting nvidia hardware limit.

Upon rounding global size to the nearest 1024 multiple and explicitly specifying  local size to be 1024 this fixed the problem for offset of 3000 but still the problem remains if offset is set to 65000. Note that rounding requires adding additional check in the kernel for not attempting to process over 1075021th element.

For offset of 65000 the kernel for the first 65000 work items just sets R[0]=0. That's another large inefficiency. This can be done on the host and the kernel can be scheduled to proces starting from 65000. Here is how this can be done:

First the kernel:

```
std::string kernel_code=
        "__kernel void test(__global float* A,__global float* R) {"
            "int i = get_global_id(0);"
            "if(i >= 1075021)" // don't process if over
            "    return;"
            "float vm=0;"
            "for(int j=i-65000;j<=i;++j)"
                "vm+=A[j];"
            "R[i]=vm;"
    "}";
```

Now use the offset:

```
size_t n=1075021;
size_t offset=65000; // define our offset
// create buffers on the device
cl::Buffer buffer_A(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(float)*n);
cl::Buffer buffer_R(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(float)*n);

float *A = new float[n];
float *R = new float[n];
memset(R,0,sizeof(float)*offset); // set to zero first 'offset' elements
```

And schedule the kernel taking into account the offset:

```
int local_size=1024;
int global_size = ((n-offset)/local_size+1)*local_size; // calculate required global size taking into account the offset
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_test,cl::NDRange(offset),cl::NDRange(global_size),cl::NDRange(local_size)); // schedule kernel using our offset
ret=queue.finish();

//read result R from the device to array R
ret=queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_R,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(float)*(n-offset),&R[offset]); // read modified data only
```

Also note that hardware watchdog timer may be killing your kernel if the execution time is taking too long - I think that is usually more than 5 seconds. If that's the case you may consider increasing the timeout to say 60 seconds or disable it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the issue is solved by changing of the kernel execution timeout TdrDelay, that is, at least in Windows 10, only 2 seconds and the execution time of the kernel was 2,1 seconds